# Seeking Correct Way to Update a React state variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

In one of my components, I define a state variable like this: `const [mediaList, setMediaList] = React.useState<Array<Media>>([]);`

`Media` is simply a TypeScript type of various properties.

I offer the user the ability to edit some of the properties.  Here's the code I've written to update certain properties in the media files they've selected:

```
const changedMediaIds: Array<string> = mediaIds;

setMediaList(mediaList.map(media => {
  return changedMediaIds.includes(media.mediaId)
    ? {
        ...media,
        description: metaDataValues.hasOwnProperty('description') ? metaDataValues.description : media.description,
        dateCreated: metaDataValues.hasOwnProperty('dateCreated') ? metaDataValues.dateCreated : media.dateCreated,
        privacy: metaDataValues.hasOwnProperty('privacy') ? metaDataValues.privacy : media.privacy,
          }
    : media
}));
```

I'm posting this to double-check that my update of the `mediaList` state variable is correct.  Obviously I'm trying to avoid state mutation, which React frowns upon.

What concerns me is that my `useEffect` functions which have `mediaList` as a dependency are firing because of this update ... and in an endless loop no less.

Comment: If your `useEffect` has `mediaList` as a dependency it will fire everytime the value of `mediaList` changes. What happens is: `setMediaList` changes the value of `mediaList`. Now as your `useEffect` has this in its dependency array, it will run again.

Can you provide more context on how you want your flow to be?

Comment: This is a pretty common situation, so `useState` has a [built-in solution](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state): `setMediaList` can accept either the updated value, or a function that updates the value based on the previous value. Change `setMediaList(mediaList.map(..))` to e.g. `setMediaList(prevMediaList => prevMediaList.map(..))` – this will allow you to remove `mediaList` from the deps for `useEffect`.

Comment: Thank you both.  I need to investigate further what's going on in my app.

Comment: Quick Update: Like is sometimes the case with software development, the bug was not at all what I suspected.  It turned out that including an `onUpdate` callback function in a different `useEffect` function in my child component was the culprit.  Not the first time that dependency recommendations have caused endless loops!

Answer (score 0):

Closed as per my final comment.  But the advice from @Satej Bidval and @motto was solid and appreciated!